# How to place a jpeg into tkinter (python3.4)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter code that can generate a window with an image on it. This is the area that keeps giving me an error:

```
window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry('1100x900')
window.title('Hello World')
lab1= tk.Label(window, text='Input the desired delay time')
btn=tk.Button(window, text='Go to new window', bg='Blue', command=NewTab)
btn2=tk.Button(window, text='Leave', bg='Red', command=close)
imgset=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgpath))
img = tk.Label(window, image=imgset)
img.pack()

lab1.pack()
btn.pack()
btn2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

where imagepath is a path to a picture in the my pictures folder

and this is the error I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonScripts\trunk\Personal\PythonWindow_ForTiming.py", line 49, in <module>
    img = tk.Label(window, image=imgset)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2604, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2122, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Could you please include comments to help me understand, I am just learning about tkinter

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add 2 lines as following (I commented the lines in question)

```
imgset=Image.open(imgpath)
# Convert imgset to a Tkinter-compatible image object
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgset) 
img = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
# Keep a reference to the image
img.image = photo 
img.pack()
```

Elementary note: you may rename `img` to something that reflects the Label() instance better (to avoid an eventual confusion) such as `label`

You may be interested in reading [***The Tkinter PhotoImage Class***](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: Thanks this fixed that error! and was very informative